# How to login to MySQL and execute a select from command line

Tags: mysql, sql, unix

I am logging in to an sql server using the following command:

```
mysql -u root
```

Then I selected the sql database:

```
use mysql
```

After this I wanted to see everything in the users table using the following command:

```
select * FROM user;
```

But how do I combine all of these three single commands into one?

I tried:

```
mysql -u root; use mysql; select * FROM user;
```

But this did not work, it just logged me into the sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
mysql -u root -e"use mysql; select * FROM user;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'SELECT * FROM quotes' cbzquotes
```